# Cross field Validation in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-validation

I created the below directive to create cross-field validation following the Tour Of Heroes example at https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Heres my code:

```
import { ValidatorFn, FormGroup, ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms";

export const ConsentReceivedValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => 
{
    const idNumber = control.get("idNumber");
    const consent = control.get("consentConfirmed");

    return idNumber && consent && idNumber.value !== null && consent.value === true ? { 
   "ConsentReceived": true } : null;
};
```

However I get the following error:

`Type '(control: FormGroup) => ValidationErrors | null' is not assignable to type 'ValidatorFn'.`

This is how the error will be validated in html:

```
    <div>
        <app-text-input-with-label labelText="ID Number" formControlItemName="idNumber"
            [form]="contactInformationForm">
        </app-text-input-with-label>
        <app-checkbox-with-label [labelText]="getConsentText()" checkboxItemName="consentConfirmed"
            [isContactInfo]="true" [form]="contactInformationForm">
        </app-checkbox-with-label>
        <div *ngIf="contactInformationForm.errors?.consentReceived"
            class="alert alert-danger alert-sm text-left mt-1">
            Please read and tick the box before proceeding.
        </div>
        <br>
        <app-reference-input [form]="contactInformationForm"></app-reference-input>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just remove `: ValidatorFn` and it should work.

Comment: This works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const ConsentReceivedValidator: ValidatorFn = () => (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => 
{
    const idNumber = control.get("idNumber");
    const consent = control.get("consentConfirmed");

    return idNumber && consent && idNumber.value !== null && consent.value === true ? { 
   "ConsentReceived": true } : null;
};
```

a validator function looks like this. you'd need to use it like this:

```
[ConsentReceivedValidator()]
```

or just remove the typing and you can use it without calling it.

Comment: the error is a compilation error on the actual directive not when trying to use it.

Comment: I will edit my question to show how the error will be validated, maybe you can extend your solution to work with this?